# Firebase create user swift doesn't work

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

below I just typed is error showing "Cannot cover value of type '(*,*) -> Void' to expected argument type '(NSERROR!) -> Void!)'

on this line of code: what would be wrong?

```
FIREBASE_REF.createUser(email, password: password, withCompletionBlock: {(error,authData) -> Void in

@IBAction func creatAccountAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        let email = self.emailTextField.text
        let password = self.passwordTextField.text

        if email != "" && password != ""
        {
            FIREBASE_REF.createUser(email, password: password, withCompletionBlock: {(error,authData) -> Void in

            if error != nil {

                FIREBASE_REF.authUser(email, password: password, withCompletionBlock: { (error, authData) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {

                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(authData.uid, forKey: "uid")
                    }
                    else {
                        print (error)
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                print (error)
            }

            }

            )}

        else
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
FIREBASE_REF.createUser(email, password: password, withCompletionBlock: {(error) -> Void in
```

This block has probably only one parameter

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for creating a user, one just creates it and returns an error if it fails (withCompletionBlock), the other also returns the authData (withValueCompletionBlock): that's the one you want.

```
myRootRef.createUser(email, password: pw, withValueCompletionBlock: { error, result in

            if error != nil {
                print("error creating user")
            } else {
                let uid = result["uid"] as! String
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(uid, forKey: "uid")
                //pass the parameters to another function to auth the user
                self.authUserWithAuthData( email, password: pw ) 
            }

        })
```